# Assume Negation for Proof by Contradiction

Tags: coq

I have a bunch of rules, which essentially entail that some proposition P can never be true. I now have to prove that P is false using Coq. In order to do so on paper, I would assume that P holds and then arrive at a contradiction, thereby proving that P cannot hold.

I'm not quite sure how to assume that P holds for this proof, which is what I seek help with.
My current code:

```
Variables {…} : Prop.
Hypothesis rule1 : … .
Hypothesis rule2 : … .
.
.
.
Hypothesis rule6 : … .
Variable s : P. (* Assume that P holds for proof by contradiction *)
(* other Coq commands *)
(* proof is done *)
```

Could someone please confirm whether I'm going about this the right way (else, how should I be doing this?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is to prove:

```
Theorem notP := ~ P.
```

which boils down to:

```
Theorem notP := P -> False.
```

So, with a variable of type P, you need to prove the goal False.

I believe the way you're doing it is acceptable, though you probably want to put that `Variable s : p.` in a section, so that you can never reach to that s in other places where you wouldn't want to...

```
Section ProvingNotP.
Variable p : P.
Theorem notP: False.
Proof. ... Qed.
End ProvingNotP.
```

I think this should work.